# java 1.7.45 : How to get full heap dump of process instead of truncated dump

Tags: java, linux, heap-memory, heap-dump

I am using below command to get heap dump

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=/tmp/heap2.bin <pid>
```

VM opts:

```
-Xms2g -Xmx4g  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
```

`But this command generates 300+ MB bin heap dump file for process running with 1.2 GB memory`( 1.2 GB memory has been shown in RES column of top command)

***EDIT:*** I have removed :live option after  **@kdgregory** suggestion but heap dump is not generated due to `G1GC` issue ( Related SE question: [Java heap dump error with jmap command : Premature EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604102/java-heap-dump-error-with-jmap-command-premature-eof/))

My queries:

1. *How to get complete heap dump of process with other GC algorithms like CMS ?*
2. *How to get heap dump along with PermGen memory too?* (permstat from command line is not useful for me).I am interested in analysis of PermGen OutOfMemory error too.

Comment: Remove `live`; this is [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)

Comment: One good catch. But how to skip GC call?

Comment: Are you saying that it triggers GC when you omit `live`? Because doing so would rather defeat the purpose of that optional (ie, _all_ dumps would just contain live objects).

Comment: Even after removing live option, the dump size and process memory size are not matching. Dump is small compared to actual memory size

Comment: The memory being used by the application is much more than just what objects are on the heap at the moment.

Comment: The problem is there is no tool for analysis non heap data.  I use the `/proc/{pid}/mem` to see how the memory of the process is mapped out.